# Add List Element to Each Row in the Respective Column of a Matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix with i rows and j columns.

```
class(matrix)
#[1] "Incomplete"

attr(,"package")
#[1] "softImpute"
```

I also have a list of values with j elements.

I would like to add each j element to the respective j column in the matrix.

Matrix: (1,1) = 1.6 , (1,2) = 1.5 and (2,1) = 2.1.

For example if my list = [1,2,3], then the matrix is updated to:

(1,1) = 1.6+1=2.6

(1,2) = 1.5+2=3.5

(2,1) = 1.1+1 = 2.1

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
for (i in length(list)) {
  matrix_updated[,i] <- matrix[,i] + list[i]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mel and welcome to SO! It's a little tough trying to understand what you're trying to do, here. Could you provide a sample of your data and clarify an example of the expected output?

Comment: Check my answer, @Mel. Accpet it if it addresses your problem.

Comment: I have error as my table is an Incomplete matrix. I try the below for loop but it doesn't work
for (i in length(beta)) {
  table_updated[,i] <- table[,i] + list[i]
}

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan i believe my object is an incomplete matrix

Comment: Have you tried my code on your incomplete matrix? And it does not work?

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan Yes i have tried, it does not work for Incomplete matrix unfortunately :(

Comment: Then give an example of incomplete matrix and I can see what can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `sweep()`

```
mat <- matrix(c(1.6, 1.1, 0.9, 1.5, 1.2, 0.8, 1.9, 1.3, 0.7), 3, 3)
lst <- list(1,2,3)

sweep(mat, MARGIN = 2, STATS = unlist(lst), FUN = '+')

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  2.6  3.5  4.9
[2,]  2.1  3.2  4.3
[3,]  1.9  2.8  3.7
```

And to fix your original function, you need to use `[[` to extract the first element from your list:

```
matrix_updated <- mat

for (i in seq_len(length(lst))) {
  matrix_updated[,i] <- mat[,i] + lst[[i]]
}
matrix_updated
```

Also, please do not name your variables `matrix` and `list`. They are also functions in [r](/questions/tagged/r).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for you using `purrr` package:

Imagine we have this initial table:

```
library(purrr)

table_IJ <- matrix( round(10 *runif(20)), nrow = 5,ncol = 3)

> table_IJ
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    7    3
[2,]    5    2    7
[3,]    7    2    2
[4,]    7    4    9
[5,]    3    7    9
```

And this is the list:

```
lst <- list(1,2,3)
> lst
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

The final operation to update each column is the following:

```
updated_table_IJ <- map2_df(as.data.frame(table_IJ), lst, function(x,y) x + y)
```

This basically adds the respective list element to the corresponding column of the table!

```
> updated_table_IJ
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     V1    V2    V3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     5     9     6
2     6     4    10
3     8     4     5
4     8     6    12
5     4     9    12
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two other methods using @Cole's data.

Replicate values of `lst` based on column `mat`

```
mat + unlist(lst)[col(mat)]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  2.6  2.5  2.9
#[2,]  3.1  3.2  3.3
#[3,]  3.9  3.8  3.7
```

Or using double transpose method we can do

```
t(t(mat) + unlist(lst))
```